# Characteristic polynomial forms a basis for a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, summation, numerical-methods

This comes out of the book called Numerical analysis by Quarteroni, et al.

Prove that the characteristic polynomial $l_i\in\mathbb{P}_n$ defined in (8.3) form a basis for $\mathbb{P}_n$

Background information:

Theorem 8.1 - Given $n+1$ distinct points $x_0,\ldots,x_n$ and $n+1$ corresponding values $y_0,\ldots,y_n$ there exists a unique polynomial $\prod_n\in\mathbb{P}_n$ such that $\prod_n(x_i) = y_i$ for $i=0,\ldots,n$

proof of theorem 8.1: To prove existence, let us use a constructive  approach, providing an expression for $\prod_n$. Denoting by $\{l_i\}_{i=0}^{n}$ a basis for $\mathbb{P}_n$, then $\prod_n$ admits a representation on such a basis of the form $\prod_n(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n}b_i l_i(x)$ with the property that $$\prod_n(x_i) = \sum_{i=0}^{n}b_i l_i(x) = y_i, i = 0,\ldots,n$$ If we define (this is (8.3)) $$l_i\in\mathbb{P}_n: l_i(x) = \prod_{j=0,j\neq i}\frac{x-x_j}{x_i - x_j} i=0,\ldots,n$$ then $l_i(x_j) = \delta_{ij}$ and we immediately get from (8.2) that $b_i = y_i$.
The polynomials $\{l_i, i = 0,\ldots, n \}$ form a basis for $\mathbb{P}_n$. The proof continues to show that as a consequence we get Lagrange yada yada...

Anyways, here is my attempted proof for the problem above:

Given $n+1$ distinct points $x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_n$ we can define the Lagrange characteristic polynomials $$l_i(x) = \prod_{j=0,j\neq i}\frac{x-x_j}{x_i - x_j}$$ Suppose we have a polynomial $\mathbb{P}_n$ of degree at most $n$ defined by $$p(x) = \alpha_o + \alpha_1 x + \ldots + \alpha_n x^n$$ Now I need to show that $l_i(x)$ forms a basis for this polynomial but I am not sure how to show this, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$
l_i(x)=\dfrac{(x-x_0)\cdots(x-x_{i-1})(x-x_{i+1})\cdots(x-x_{n})}{(x_i-x_0)\cdots(x_i-x_{i-1})(x_i-x_{i+1})\cdots(x_i-x_{n})}
$$
So we have
$$
l_i(x_j)=\begin{cases}
1,\quad\text{for }j=i
\\0,\quad\text{for }j\ne i
\end{cases}
$$
Now let 
$$
l(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n p(x_i) l_i(x)
$$
$l(x)$ and $p(x)$ must be identical for they coincide at $n+1$ points of $x_0, \cdots, x_n$, but both have degree of $n$.

Comment: Could you provide more information, I am still a tad lost on your Hint

Comment: Read your proof or the proof of theorem 8.1?

Comment: My proof. It is consistent with theorem 8.1.

Comment: yea, not sure why this does not make sense to me

Comment: Nevermind I got it now